# zsh: how to delete contents in folder without deleting the folder?

Tags: linux, unix, zsh

I am using zsh and I want to delete contents of a folder without deleting the folder itself. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: An answer which actually works is here: [How can I delete all files in a folder, but not the folder itself, in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72819132/how-can-i-delete-all-files-in-a-folder-but-not-the-folder-itself-in-zsh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rm -r myfolder/*` will delete all files in that folder that do not begin with a dot.

Really the simplest solution is `rm -rf myfolder && mkdir myfolder`.

Comment: Fine, but note that you'll lose any non-default permissions on the folder.

Comment: Sorry, but the question explicitly states "without deleting the folder". Maybe some running process needs it, maybe you want to keep the permissions. This does not answer the question as stated.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `rm -r path/to/dir/*`.