# How can I delete all files in a folder, but not the folder itself, in zsh?

Tags: zsh, rm

Unfortunately [zsh: how to delete contents in folder without deleting the folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176446/zsh-how-to-delete-contents-in-folder-without-deleting-the-folder) does not have any good answer.

I'm currently using `rm -rf {.,}*` and if that fails because there is no hidden file in the folder I do another `rm -rf *`. This is of course annoying, not least because I am prompted for confirmation twice (so just putting them in a row with `;` wouldn't solve much.)

Is there a solution that

- works in the presence and absence of hidden files;
- does not delete the current folder, even temporarily;
- prompts only once?

It must work in the current folder. If it also works for a specified folder, that's nice to have but not a must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zsh has the `GLOB_DOTS` setting to make `*` match hidden files; you can enable this globally with `setopt glob_dots` if you want, or for a pattern with the `(D)` glob qualifier.

```
% print dir/*(D)
```

So to remove all files (hidden and unhidden) you can use:

```
% setopt glob_dots
% rm -rf dir/*

# Disable glob_dots for just this pattern:
% rm -rf dir/*(^D)
```

Or:

```
% rm -rf dir/*(D)
```

Unless I missed something, I believe this should do what you want.

For more information see `man zshexpn` (which is comprehensive, but also quite dense and not an easy read; [section 5.9 of the Zsh User Guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html#l135) is a more gentle introduction, and I recommend spending some time reading through all of the User Guide because there's lots of useful things in there).

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the files inside a folder without deleting the actual folder by just adding `*` after a slash, for example:

```
rm -f my_folder/*
```

That way it will delete all files inside `my_folder` but not the actual folder itself. You can use the option `r` to recursive delete all inside the folder.

**Update for one liner:**

You could then use in the same command:

```
rm -rf my_folder/* my_folder/.*
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work if there are hidden files.

Comment: Oh i get your point now, you want to delete in a single command both hidden and non hidden files. For hidden you would add `/.*` but what won't delete non hidden.

Comment: There is still an issue with the second commandline. Try to have one non-hidden file in a folder and do `rm -rf * .*`. zsh will complain and nothing gets deleted.

Comment: I added a screenshot to reproduce, what does ZSH complain about?

Comment: The problem is that either `*` or `.*` may not match anything, leading to a "no matches found" error for one of them. You can use `*(N) .*(N)` to enable the `null_glob` option, so it won't error out, but easier to just use the `(D)` qualifier.

Comment: @DavidMauricio sorry I was unclear: ONLY a non-hidden file and no hidden ones. -- Thanks, Martin, these qualifiers are exactly what I was missing the whole time!